# Css- word-wrap feature

Tags: css, word-wrap

I am using the word-wrap property from CSS3 and it works fine in IE but does not seem to work in firefox or chrome. Based on all the reading I've done it should work in firefox for sure. Can someone explain or put forth a theory on why it might not be working

Comment: Can you show some code and a short example?

Comment: Which versions of these browsers?

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know , this properties only work's in `IE/Win, Safari, e Shiira`

***EDIT:***

made some search and found this doc:

check [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap) and see if help's you.